# Selected city change on every page refresh and need to set again

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

User from front page ,select the city from below list and as per search product are displayed.

But after the every product displayed , page reload and City selected get changed to First city and user need to select again city for every search.

Need help how to overcome this issue and set the city to user selected ,not refreshed every time .

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('autocompleteController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.cities = [
        {name: 'London'},
        {name: 'Paris'},
        {name: 'Newyork'},
    ];
    $scope.selectedCities = $scope.cities[0];
    var initalizeproduct = function() {
        $scope.products = $http.get("/getproduct/"+$scope.selectedCities.name).success(function(data){
            $scope.products = data.products;
        });
    }
    initalizeproduct($scope.products);
    $scope.changeCity = function() {
        initalizeproduct();
    }
    $scope.onSelectPart = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedproducts = item;
        window.location.href = "/product/"+$scope.selectedproducts.fields.slug;
    };

});
```

From HTML Page :

```
<select ng-model="selectedCities" ng-change="changeCity()" ng-options="cities.name for cities in cities" style="background :transparent; border:0px; outline: none;">
            </select>
```

Comment: <select ng-model="selectedCities" ng-change="changeCity()" ng-options="cities.name for cities in cities" style="background :transparent; border:0px; outline: none;">
     </select>

Comment: This is how it is called from HTML page

Comment: *page reload and City selected get changed*: why does your page reload? Angularjs is for single page apps, you should never need reload.

Comment: Or if you use Angularjs together with a website/app that reloads by default you should be able to prefill the field with data from session/cookies or request parameters. Or load the search results with ajax/pjax to prevent page reload.

Comment: Why you need reload the page?

Comment: Review [how to use routing in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). Using `window.location.href` is not a good strategy when using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `window.location.href = "...";` with:

```
$http
    .get("/product/"+$scope.selectedproducts.fields.slug)
    .then(function( ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ response) {
       var data = response.data; 
       // Get the HTML part from 'data' that you would like to display and add it to DOM
    });
```

to begin with.

Comment: The `.success` method is deprecated and [removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: Does `.then` work? Honestly.. I'm not an Angularjs expert :)

Comment: The `.then` method returns a response object of which `data` is one of its properties. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.6 - http](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/docs/guide/migration#migrate1.5to1.6-ng-services-$http)